# Using static attributes in c++?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-methods

i have an assignment where i need to read the words from different documents and store them in a vector of strings, i made this vector static so that each document would just add their words to the vector so that i can have one list of all the words.
i made a document class and in the header i wrote :

```
class document {
public:

    document(string filename);

    static vector<string> words;
    string name;
    vector<int> frequency;
    void getFrequency();
    static void  addWord(string wordd);
```

in the document.cpp file implemented the addWord method with the following :

```
 static void  document::addWord(string wordd){


    vector<string>::iterator i = find(words.begin(), words.end(), wordd);

    if (i == words.end()) {
        words.push_back(wordd);
    }
 }
```

however this doesn't work and every time i try to build the code it gives me this error message

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/assignment1 mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX rm
-f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/assignment1 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "document::words", referenced from:
      document::getFrequency()      in main.o
      document::addWord(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/assignment1] Error 1 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: You just *declared* `document::words`, you also need to *define* it in one of your cpp files.

Comment: It's rather meaningless that a document doesn't store its own words. Essentially this problem doesn't need the document class at all (because it doesn't represent a document anyway) and seeing that you want to query the frequency of words, a map<string, int> would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error which this error message is about is that you have declared `document::words` but you haven't defined it. A definition of this lives outside the class definition, typically in the class's translation unit. You need to have definition which looks something like this:

```
static std::vector<std::string> document::words;
```

That said, please not that static data is pretty much like slightly better controlled global data. Especially with concurrent programs having anything which is shared for all object is a Bad Idea. If this thing is mutable it is an even worse idea (BTW, the also applies if the global data is referred to as "Singleton": just because something is allegedly a design pattern doesn't mean it is somehow blessed and the problems are gone away).

Answer (score 0):

Remove keyword `static` from function definition (from .cpp file).

When `static` is used in function definition then the meaning of the word is that function is visible only in current compilation unit (similar to unnamed namespace). So, just remove it from .cpp.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is not true.  The question was about a static member anyway, but static methods are also valid: they have the same scope and access as a non-static method, but aren't associated with an instance (so you can call them with no object).

Comment: Hm, now that I read the build output I see that I gave the wrong answer. Still, AFAIK, declaration of `addWord` method should have static keyword, but definition should not. I believe that, after `document::words` is defined, there should pop up another linker error about missing document::addWord().

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "document::words"
```

is telling you that your static data member was never actually created: you declared it in the header, but never told the compiler where to store the object.

This is sort of a non-problem in your case, but in a larger project with many `.cpp` files including the same header, it's important the static object is only allocated once.

Add this line to `document.cpp`:

```
vector<string> document::words;
```

It's exactly like a global variable declaration (since that's really what a static member is), except for the scoped name.